# Copy Two Dimensional ArrayList as new

Tags: java, arraylist

So the issue I'm having is after copying the 2d arraylist, changing the element from one 2d arraylist affects the other 2d arraylist. I want them to be completely separate in memory.

First example shows how it works correctly with 1d arraylists...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class QuickTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> secondList = new ArrayList<>();

        Integer counter = 2;
        for(int arrI = 0; arrI < 4; arrI++, counter+=2){
            firstList.add(counter);
        }

        secondList = new ArrayList<>(firstList);

        System.out.println("firstList.get(2) = " + firstList.get(2));
        System.out.println("secondList.get(2) = " + secondList.get(2));

        firstList.set(2, 7);

        System.out.println("firstList.get(2) = " + firstList.get(2));
        System.out.println("secondList.get(2) = " + secondList.get(2));
    }
}
```

Expected output:

[image]

Notice how the element from the first arraylist is changed but not the second arraylist element is not changed. This is good and what we want.

Now to try and copy the 2d arraylists...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class QuickTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> firstTwoDimList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> secondTwoDimList = new ArrayList<>();

        firstTwoDimList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        firstTwoDimList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        firstTwoDimList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

        Integer counter = 2;
        for(int arrI = 0; arrI < firstTwoDimList.size(); arrI++, counter+=2){
            firstTwoDimList.get(arrI).add(counter);
            counter+=2;
            firstTwoDimList.get(arrI).add(counter);
        }

        secondTwoDimList = new ArrayList<>(firstTwoDimList);

        System.out.println("firstTwoDimList.get(1).get(0) = " + firstTwoDimList.get(1).get(0));
        System.out.println("secondTwoDimList.get(1).get(0) = " + secondTwoDimList.get(1).get(0));

        firstTwoDimList.get(1).set(0, 7);

        System.out.println("firstTwoDimList.get(1).get(0) = " + firstTwoDimList.get(1).get(0));
        System.out.println("secondTwoDimList.get(1).get(0) = " + secondTwoDimList.get(1).get(0));
    }
}
```

Unexpected output:

[image]

Anyone have any idea what the reason for this is, and what the best solution would be?

Comment: Java is pass by reference, which is the likely explanation for what you are seeing.  But, why are you working with lists of lists?

Comment: Yes, I'm working with a lists of lists (up to 4d arraylists in my program).

Comment: So I think creating a copy of pass by value would be the better solution here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what is happening in the 1D array list case, in terms of references:

[image]

This is what is happening in the 2D array list case:

[image]

This means that when you copy an array list using this:

```
new ArrayList<>(someOldArrayList)
```

the items themselves don't get copied, only a new array list object is created, referring to all the items in the old array list.

In the second case, you are only changing what array list 2's items are, but index 1 of first list and second list refers to the same array list 2.

To fix this, you need to copy the array lists inside first list and second list as well. One way to do this:

```
secondList = new ArrayList<>(firstList.stream().map(x -> new ArrayList<>(x)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: I guess the 7 in 1D array should be 8?

Comment: @EugeneS That is supposed to show the result after setting the item at index 2 to be 7. I didn't intend to show everything in the array list.

Comment: right so it's only copying the first dimension as new.... but the second dimension as a reference to what both lists are pointing to. I was hoping for a simple solution to copy both dimensions as new...

Comment: @FiddleFreak Is the suggestion I gave not simple enough?

Comment: `Collectos` isn't recognized for me.

Comment: @FiddleFreak Oops! Typo. Edited now. Have you never used the Stream API before?

Comment: I think i have used the stream once... but it's been a while. Also the compiler gives a suggestion replacing `new ArrayList<>(x)` with lambda's (maybe you know more about this...) Anyway... looks like I just had to replace the `secondTwoDimList = firstTwoDimList;` line with your line `secondTwoDimList = new ArrayList<>(firstTwoDimList.stream().map(x -> new ArrayList<>(x)).collect(Collectors.toList()));`

Comment: @FiddleFreak Ah yes, you can replace that with `ArrayList::new`, but I like `new ArrayList<>(x)` better :) And you should replace `secondTwoDimList = firstTwoDimList;` with that.

Comment: hmmm seems to give me a compiler error when trying that. I think we'll just go with what is working here. Thanks again...

Comment: collapsing the code more we get to the 
`secondList = firstList.stream().map(ArrayList::new).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 2):

You should iterate through the size of the first dimension of the `firstTwoDimArray` and add new reference of each second dimension to the `secondTwoDimArray`. i.e.

```
for(int index = 0; index < firstTwoDimList.size(); index++) {
    secondTwoDimList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(firstTwoDimList.get(index)));
}
```

Comment: creating a function to do this is also what I was thinking... I just wanted to ask if there was a built in library that does this for me. I suppose not?

Comment: I don't think so if there is any built-in method to do this. Let me know if you find any :)

Comment: Will do friend, that's why I'm here :) Also, I think a `foreach` loop is a bit cleaner :) See the answer I gave in the first function...

Comment: looks like sweeper had a good solution using the stream and collectors library. See below in his answer...

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your first and second example is that in the second one you use `get()`. This `get()` returns a new variable, so you assign the integers to it and not to the original `ArrayList`.

If you want to assign a value:

```
firstTwoDimList.set(1, new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 7)));
```

Comment: so, lets say I make a million copies and start changing the values of all the lists... I would have to use that line for each copy? Is there an easier way to just copy it as a new array without having to worry about changing the other lists as well?

Comment: Well, you were not changing the other arrays. The assumption that your copy still referencing to the original variable is wrong. You can test that by comparing the objects like this `object1 == object2`. This compares the actual references and in your case will return `false` which is good (means that's not the same object). So your copying is fine. It's just the way you were assigning the new variables was wrong.

Comment: I realize they will be different objects due to different elements (which is the purpose of why I want to keep them separate in my original program). I also understand your solution (setting value as new variable and not changing what is held in memory... aka assigning a new memory slot for that variable). I was just hoping for an easier way when creating a copy, it would create a pass by value and not pass by reference. So the two arraylists would be completely separate in memory. I suppose the easiest way would be to create a `twoDimArrCopy()` function...

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was looking for something like this...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class QuickTest {
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getTwoDimArrListCopy(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> original){
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> copy = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ArrayList<Integer> arr: original){
            copy.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(arr));
        }

        return copy;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> firstTwoDimList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> secondTwoDimList = new ArrayList<>();

        firstTwoDimList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        firstTwoDimList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        firstTwoDimList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

        Integer counter = 2;
        for(int arrI = 0; arrI < firstTwoDimList.size(); arrI++, counter+=2){
            firstTwoDimList.get(arrI).add(counter);
            counter+=2;
            firstTwoDimList.get(arrI).add(counter);
        }

        secondTwoDimList = getTwoDimArrListCopy(firstTwoDimList);

        System.out.println("firstTwoDimList.get(1).get(0) = " + firstTwoDimList.get(1).get(0));
        System.out.println("secondTwoDimList.get(1).get(0) = " + secondTwoDimList.get(1).get(0));

        firstTwoDimList.get(1).set(0, 7);

        System.out.println("firstTwoDimList.get(1).get(0) = " + firstTwoDimList.get(1).get(0));
        System.out.println("secondTwoDimList.get(1).get(0) = " + secondTwoDimList.get(1).get(0));
    }
}
```

I was just hoping there was a built in library that would do that `getTwoDimArrListCopy()` function for me...